# Splitting DateTime by midnight

Tags: php, datetime

I have a time interval which consists of two DateTimes:

```
array(
    "DATE_TIME_FROM" => new \DateTime(...) , //2021-01-01 10:00
    "DATE_TIME_TO" => new \DateTime(...), //2021-01-02 01:00
)
```

If any of these datetimes go beyound the day then an existing array should be split into two like I shown in an example below:

```
array(
    "DATE_TIME_FROM" => new \DateTime(...) , //2021-01-01 10:00
    "DATE_TIME_TO" => new \DateTime(...), //2021-01-02 00:00
), 
array(
    "DATE_TIME_FROM" => new \DateTime(...) , //2021-01-02 00:00
    "DATE_TIME_TO" => new \DateTime(...), //2021-01-02 01:00
)
```

Is it possible somehow? Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried to use Bitrix CMS built-in DateTime class which is quite limeted in functionality. When I rolled back to PHP DateTime class the solution became quite clear.

Comment: What is the purpose of Monday? BTW I checked 2021-01-01 is Friday.

Comment: @shingo might be, I took random dates. Don't pay attention on day, it is not really relevant to this question.

Comment: Please remove the irrelvant part. So what you want is from `DATE_TIME_FROM` to `the midnight of DATE_TIME_TO` and from `the midnight of DATE_TIME_TO` to `DATE_TIME_TO`, right?

Comment: @shingo if any of these datetime go beyound the day then an existing interval should be split into two like I shown in an example above.

Comment: There's no such thing as `2021-01-01 24:00`. After `2021-01-01 23:59` comes `2021-01-02 00:00`.

Comment: @volkerschulz 24:00 does exist in some systems (but rare) and there are time units lower than second, even PHP can handle microseconds.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell 24:00 does not exist for the DateTime object. And yes, I've used microseconds in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the midnight of DATE_TIME_TO:

```
$midnight = clone $arr['DATE_TIME_TO'];
$midnight->modify('midnight');
```

If it is greater than DATE_TIME_FROM, split the array into two:

```
if($midnight > $arr['DATE_TIME_FROM'])
    $arr = [
        [
            'DATE_TIME_FROM' => $arr['DATE_TIME_FROM'],
            'DATE_TIME_TO' => $midnight
        ],
        [
            'DATE_TIME_FROM' => $midnight,
            'DATE_TIME_TO' => $arr['DATE_TIME_TO']
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through a `DatePeriod` with a `DateInterval` of 1 day from start `DateTime` to end `DateTime`:

```php
function splitDates(DateTime $start, DateTime $end) : array {
    $start_datetime = clone $start;
    $end_datetime = clone $end;
    $start_datetime->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
    $end_datetime->setTime(23, 59, 59, 999999);
    $end_datetime->modify('+1 microsecond');
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($start_datetime, $interval ,$end_datetime);
    $resultset = [];
    foreach($daterange as $key=>$date) {
        $end_datetime = clone $date;
        $end_datetime->setTime(23, 59, 59, 999999);
        $end_datetime->modify('+1 microsecond');
        $resultset[] = [
            'start' => $date,
            'end'   => $end_datetime,
        ];
    }
    $resultset[0]['start'] = $start;
    $resultset[array_key_last($resultset)]['end'] = $end;
    return $resultset;
}


$results = splitDates(new DateTime('2021-01-01 10:00:00'), new DateTime('2021-01-04 01:00:00'));
var_dump($results);
```

If you want the end of a day to be `23:59:59.999999` rather than midnight of the following day, simply remove the two lines reading `$end_datetime->modify('+1 microsecond');`

https://3v4l.org/uPLaZ

**Edit:** This function works with any number of days between start and end date, if the end date is guaranteed to be on the same or the following day of start date, go with the answer posted by @shingo.